# Is it possible that EWOULDBLOCK be returned when partial data is received

Tags: sockets, nonblocking

When reading from socket, if EWOULDBLOCK is returned ..is it possible that only partial data is read?
Or is it that when EWOULDBLOCK is returned data read is 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When reading from socket, if EWOULDBLOCK is returned

`EWOULDBLOCK` is returned when no data is available without blocking.

> ..is it possible that only partial data is read?

No.

> Or is it that when EWOULDBLOCK is returned data read is 0 ?

`EWOULDBLOCK` is returned when no data is available without blocking.

Answer (score -1):

When reading from a O_NONBLOCK socket, **recv** will return -1 and set *EWOULDBLOCK* or *EAGAIN* if there is no data available.

Is it possible that only partial data es read?

YES: calling **recv** will return as much information as is currently available - up to the requested amount.

You should also take a look at the recv's flags, specifically *MSG_WAITALL* and *MSG_PEEK*.

If recv returns 0 it means the socket has been properly closed at the peer and there is no data pending.

Comment: If EWOULDBLOCK occurs, no data has been read at all: there is no possibility of 'partial data'. Conversely, if any data was read, EWOULDBLOCK did not occur.

Comment: Yes you are right. I understood the OP was trying to ask:
If I request 1000 bytes and there are only 500 available, what happens? 
What does recv return? 
And I said, it returns as much as is available up to the requested amount or EWOULDBLOCK if no data available.

Comment: recv() returns 500. The question isn't about partial reads. The question is 'if EWOULDBLOCK is returned ... is it possible that only partial data is returned?' The answer to that is 'no'. Not 'yes'.